# Bound on metric of product spaces given isometric extension

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X=Y\times Z$ be the product of two compact metric spaces, with metric $d_X(x_1,x_2)=\max\{d_Y(y_1,y_2),d(z_1,z_2)\}$ (where $y_i=\pi_Y(x_i)$ and similarly for $z_i$), and let $f:X\to X$ be continuous with the property that $d_X(f(x_1),f(x_2))=d_X(x_1,x_2)$ whenever $y_1=y_2.$ (We shall call this condition $(*)$).

I am trying to prove that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$, such that if $d_Y(y_1,y_2)<\delta$ and $d_Z(z_1,z_2)<\varepsilon$ then $d_X(f(x_1),f(x_2))<2\varepsilon$. As $X$ and $Y$ are compact we know that $f$ and $\pi_Y$ are uniformly continuous, which we will definitely need (at least that of $f$). Now I would be able to complete this proof if we could prove that $(*)$ implies that we can choose $\delta$ small enough so that $d_Z(z_1,z_2)<\varepsilon$ implies that $d_Z(\pi_Z\circ f(x_1),\pi_Z\circ f(x_2))\leq \varepsilon$. However, the most natural approach given $(*)$ would be to show that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $d_Y(y_1,y_2)<\delta$ implies that $d_X(f(x_1),f(x_2))\leq d_X(x_1,x_2)+\varepsilon$.

This problem is rather frustrating, because intuitively it seems clear that $(*)$ implies the latter approach, but I cannot come up with a proof. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $d_X(f(x'), f(x'')) < \epsilon$ whenever $d_X(x', x'')<\delta$. So, if $d_Y(y_1,y_2)<\delta$ and $d_Y(z_1,z_2)<\epsilon$, then 
$$
d_X(f(y_1, z_1), f(y_2, z_2)) \le 
d_X(f(y_1, z_1), f(y_2, z_1)) + d_X(f(y_2, z_1), f(y_2, z_2))
< \epsilon + \epsilon 
$$
as desired. We only need $f$ to be $1$-Lipschitz in the second variable, i.e., 
$$d_X(f(x_1),f(x_2)) \le d_X(x_1,x_2)\quad\text{when } y_1=y_2$$

Comment: Ahh the good ol' triangle inequality. Don't I feel a fool